# Adding JS script tag to React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a script.js file on the server which is written in pure javascript (vanilla) and returns HTML form with some functionality.
I download it by first `<script>` tag and use functions from script.js in second `<script>` tag in .html file and it is working. But I don't know how to make it run in React. I tried to do so, but not working.

script.js

```js
var lib = lib || (function() {
  var _args = {};

  return {
    init: function(Args) {
      _args = Args;
    },
    func: function() {
      ...some logic and use document.write
      for render
    }
  }
}())
```

In HTML, it works

```html
<script src='http://someurl.com/checkout'></script>
<script>
  lib.init(...some args);
  lib.func();
</script>
```

In React, it doesn't work

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class Checkout extends Component {

  state = {}

  componentDidMount = async() => {
    axios.get("http://someurl.com/checkout")
      .then(res => {
        const scriptInit = document.createElement("script");
        scriptInit.src = "http://someurl.com/checkout";
        // or scriptInit.text = res.data;
        scriptInit.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptInit.async = true;
        const scriptFunc = document.createElement("script");
        scriptFunc.text = "lib.init(...); lib.func();";
        scriptFunc.async = true;
        const script = scriptInit.outerHTML + scriptFunc.outerHTML;
        this.setState({
          script
        });
      })

  }

  render() {
    const __html = this.state.script || "";
    return <div id = "checkout"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
      {
        __html
      }
    }
    />
  }
}

export default Checkout;
```

Render div tag with all script tags but with 1110 x 0 resolution

Comment: What do you mean by `but with 1110 x 0 resolution` how the resolution relates to the script issue?

Comment: I have tried script*.innerHTML, but it returns js code from script.js

Comment: @MoshFeu This is written when I open the chrome devtolls' (F12) Elements tab

Comment: Make sense. But I still try to understand what's the issue. Is it that the script is not running?

Comment: Written you mean that this is the dimension of the script or the containg div tag? If so, it's not relevant because script doesn't need to have dimension.

Comment: It doesn't render (or cannot use functions from script.js) or download script.js data

Comment: I want add <script> tag in React DOM in .js or .jsx file, because React project consists only one /public/index.html root file

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/25/gotchas-with-dynamically-adding-script-tags-to-html) could explain it.

Comment: @MoshFeu I change document.write to document.createElement and document.body.appendChild and etc. in script.js - It works in html but not in React

Comment: are you using some library in your javascript things? because it should work since react is a javascript base. Maybe you need to translate your pure js into react code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the functions after your script loads.You would not need axios for this,you can acheive this using the onload callback for the script load.

```
componentDidMount(){
 const script = document.createElement("script");
 document.head.appendChild(script);
 script.src = "http://someurl.com/checkout";
 script.async = true;
 script.onload = () => this.runScriptMethods();
}

runScriptMethods(){
  lib.init(...);
  lib.func()
}
```

Comment: But if my script render some elements using document.write and must be in body and lib functions are implemented in script.js?

Comment: Thanks it works, but only with the help of eval("lib.init()...") in runScriptMethods() - it is not so good

Comment: No, it's not good and I'm not sure why you need the eval. If you're trying to run it without (e.g. `lib.init()`) what's happening?

Comment: @MoshFeu 'lib' is not defined. Because lib object is defined in script.js on another url/server

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the script is executing in the context of the website. And surly, it will not be   different than run it with `eval`.